# PHP Variable used in a variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm new to PHP so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

How do you include a variable in a variable?

What I mean is:

```
<?php

   $variable_a = 'Adam';
   $variable_b = '$variable_a';

?>
```

In other words the second variable is the same as the first one.

I won't bother explaining why I need to do it (it will confuse you!), but I just want to know firstly if it's possible, and secondly how to do it, because I know that code there doesn't work.

Cheers,

Adam.

Comment: Better to write without quotes, but if you want to use quotes then use double quotes instead of single.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Comment: dont forget: [PHP variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: Read the reference variable and the variables in single in double quotes. it will remove your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the variables to be equal, use:

```
$variable_b = $variable_a;
```

If you want the second variable to contain the first, use [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
$variable_b = "my other variable is: $variable_a";
```

Or concatenation:

```
$variable_b = 'my other variable is: ' . $variable_a;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the quotes, they indicate a string. Just point to the variable directly, like this:

```
$variable_b = $variable_a;
```

Comment: Ahhhh! So you don't include the quotes. No wonder it was outputting as text. Thanks mate perfect!

Answer (score 2):

PHP have this advantage in producing one string variable's value based on another. To do this, write code like this:

```
$b = "My name is $name.";
```

The following code does NOT work:

```
$b = '$name';
```

Other occasions in which coding like this works are:

```
$b = <<<STRING
    Hello, my name is $name...
STRING;
```

If you want to access an array, use:

```
$b = "My ID is {$id['John Smith']}.";
```

and of course,

```
$b = <<<STRING
    Hello, my name is {$username}, my ID is {$id['John Smith']}.
STRING;
```

I recommend using {} because I frequently use Chinese charset in which occasion coding like

```
$b = "我是$age了。";
```

will cause PHP look up for variable **$age了。** and cause error.

Answer (score 1):

Either without quotes to reference the variable directly, since quotations means it's a string

```
$variable_b = $variable_a;
```

Or you can ommit the variable in double quotations, if you want it to appear in a string.

```
$variable_b = "My name is $variable_a";
```